# Subtract time from strtrotime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am trying to figure out how to subtract 1 hour form the time being outputted.  Our web server is 1 hour ahead of our time.  I am using the following to return the time a table was created in our MySQL database.

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'America/Los_Angeles');
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','database','password');  
$db = mysql_select_db('database'); 
$sql = mysql_query("SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE `name`=\"initm\"");  
$foo = mysql_fetch_array($sql);  
$ts = strtotime($foo['Create_time']);
echo "<h3>Last Updated ";
echo date('m/d/Y g:i a T', $ts);
echo "</h3>";
```

If I try to subtract time `$ts = strtotime($foo['Create_time']-3600);`

it returns Last Updated 12/31/1969 4:00 pm PST.  I understand it is subtracting from the UNIX timestamp, which is defined as the number of seconds since January 1, 1970 and not from the time in the table.

I tried adding `ini_set('date.timezone', 'America/Los_Angeles');` but it just changes the time zone outputted.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.  A novice in PHP and MySQL.

Comment: There are [militants](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143379/automatically-warn-against-the-use-of-mysql-functions-on-stack-overflow) who will tell you to avoid using the `mysql_*` function in PHP — they are deprecated, and you should use the PDO module instead.  That doesn't significantly affect the real content of this question, though.

Comment: Can you try `$ts = strtotime($foo['Create_time'])-3600;` ?

Answer (score 2):

`strtotime` assumes it's parameter is a string, and converts it to seconds. You need to do the subtraction after the conversion:

```
$ts = strtotime($foo['Create_time'])-3600;
```

Comment: For more readability you can use `$ts = strtotime($foo['Create_time'] . ' -1 hour');`

Answer (score 1):

Why not :

```
$query = "SET time_zone = '-6:00'";
```

This will set your configuration in the same way as `SET charset utf8`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Create_time) - 3600 ...
```

is far easier than multiple round-trips through PHP's and MySQL's date/time processing systems.

However, since strtotime is giving you invalid results, I'm guessing that whatever you're storing in `Create_time` is not actually a native mysql data/time value, but probably some wonky non-standard date value as a string. That means strtotime() is returning a boolean FALSE to indicate failure, and then you force PHP to convert that false to an integer `0` to handle your "minus 3600" calculation.

You should generally always store things in native formats/types, to prevent occurences such as this. Native allows you to use native facilities for processing. Custom formats mean pain/suffering